# Angular: Possible to have a model in one format but display & validate in another?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to do something like formatting a date in an input field as "mm/dd/yyyy", use the displayed input for validation, but format the model as "yy-mm-dddd" in a template driven form?

In this form, a user types in a date that is validated against a regex pattern. A '/' is added as the user types to achieve the format I'm going for.

```html
<label>Date available:
    <input type="text" name="dateAvailable" ngModel #date 
        (input)="date.value = FormatDateForView(date.value)" <!-- automatically inserts '/'s as the user types -->
        pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$">
    (blur)="applicant.dateAvailable = FormatDateForMySql(date.value)" <!-- sets the model, replacing '/' with '-' -->
</label>
    <div *ngIf="date.errors.pattern">*Date must be in mm/dd/yyyy format.</div>
```

This doesn't work. 
If I change it so that `ngModel #date` reads `ngModel #date="ngModel"`, the validation works but the `(input)` event logic no longer works.

I'm trying to do this without a second model and without doing the reformatting logic `onSubmit()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Might it be more user friendly (and easier to code) to just create three input boxes: `<box 1>/<box 2>/<box 3>`? That way the format is not attempting to change as the user types ... causing potential issues if the user types fast, types the "/" or backspaces. And it makes the values easier to validate.

Comment: I thought about this, but it's so nice when you're filling out a form to only type your number and not have to press anything to get to the next field.

Comment: You can add code to auto advance...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [2 way data binding](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html) instead of binding to the `(input)` event.

```
<input 
   type="text" 
   name="dateAvailable" 
   [(ngModel)]="FormatDateForView($event)"
   pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"
   (blur)="applicant.dateAvailable = FormatDateForMySql(date.value)" 
/>
```

Also note the substitution of `data.value` this is because...

> $event is the payload of the emitted event. In other words, `ngModelChange` takes care of extracting `target.value` from the inner `$event` payload, and simply emits that (to be technically correct, it’s actually the `DefaultValueAccessor` that takes of the extracting that value and also writing to the underlying DOM object). [Reference.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)

In this case, `ngModelChange` is wrapped up in our 2 way binding of `[(ngModel)]`. When you write `[(ngModel)]` you are actually writting:

```
[ngModel]="..." 
(ngModelChange)="..."
```

Comment: I'm getting `Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 30 in [FormatDateForView($event)=$event]`. The error added that `=$event` part. the function is only returning `event.target.value` right now

Comment: Not sure why you have `[FormatDateForView($event)=$event]` at all. It should be removed. All you need is the `NgModel` binding. @slanden

Comment: that's only part of the error message I get in the console, I was showing you in case you knew what it meant. My code looks exactly as yours does in your answer